# Python Parameter not defined

Tags: python, syntax, parameters

So i am making a program to draw specific letters using turtle and I have set up a parameter scale to effect the size and pen thickness of the  program based on a prompt to input. here is what I have... I keep getting an error saying scale is not defined.

```
import turtle

def drawLetter( letter ):
    if letter == " ":
        space(scale)
    elif letter == "i":
        i_lc(scale)
    elif letter == "I":
        i_uc(scale)
    elif letter == "s":
        s_lc(scale)
    elif letter == "S":
        s_uc(scale)
    elif letter == "C":
        c_uc(scale)
    elif letter == "c":
        c_lc(scale)


def space(scale):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward( 30 * scale )


def questionMark():
    """ Draw a question mark.
    """
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.down()
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 2 )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward( 3 )
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 5 )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 5 )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward( 15 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward ( 30 )


def i_uc(scale):
    """ Draw an upper case I.
    """
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.left( 180 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.left( 180 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward( 10 )


def i_lc(scale):
    """ Draw a lower case i.
    """
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.down()
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 11 )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward( 2 )
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 2 )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.right( 180 )
    turtle.forward( 15 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )


def s_uc(scale):
    """ Draw an upper case S.
    """
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.right( 180 )
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 )
    turtle.left( 180 )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.forward( 30 )


def s_lc(scale):
    """ Draw a lower case s.
    """
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 5 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 5 * scale )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 * scale )


def c_uc(scale):
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.forward( -20 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.forward( -20 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( -20 * scale )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )


def c_lc(scale):
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.forward( -20 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 10 * scale )
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )
    turtle.forward( -20 * scale )
    turtle.left( 90 )
    turtle.forward( -10 * scale )
    turtle.up()
    turtle.right( 90 )
    turtle.forward( 20 * scale )


def main():
    scale == input("Enter scale:")
    turtle.pensize(scale)
```

Comment: Make this post more readable by formatting your code correctly and limiting the amount of code you put in (only show what's necessary to demonstrate and reproduce the error). Far as I understand you call `c_lc(scale)` (for example) but you do not define a variable called `scale` in the "top" program which prints the letters. Hence the error.

Comment: Please, do *not* use tabs to indent. You should use 4 spaces instead of a tab. **Any** editor has an option to insert spaces instead of tab when pressing the tab key, so no excuses for this. (About why to avoid tabs: they look different in different environments, so even if in your computer the code looks right, in another the indents may be cluttered. Also when copy-pasting from website I often have problems of mixed space and tabs)

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` function you have the code

```
scale == input("Enter scale:")
```

but this is a *comparison* and not an *assignement*, so you get an error because `scale` isn't defined. To give the variable `scale` a value (and thus define it) you have to use a singe `=`.
To solve this use:

```
scale = input("Enter scale:")
```

Another thing is, that your `drawLetter(letter)` won't have access to the `scale` variable, so you have to add it as an argument there.
To solve this use:

```
def drawLetter(letter, scale):
```

A third problem is, that the `drawLetter` function is never called!